# Repeated measures ANOVA on proportions of errors

Tags: regression, anova, assumptions

Statistics help please!!
I gave subjects a multiple choice test with 3 options.
There were 2 types of questions in the test (easy and hard). The non-correct answer options were either lures or non lures. I'm interested whether the type of question (easy hard) and the type of error the student made (did they pick the lure or the non lure) interact. I have low and high performing students.
Can I simply do a 2 (between: Student type) x 2 (within: question type) x 2 (within: type of error) ANOVA, using the proportion out of all errors made for each type of question as the DV? (eg, I have the proportion of responses for Easy Lure, Easy Non Lure, Hard Lure, Hard Non Lure)?